# python can't open file with both read and write capability

Tags: python

I'm going to open a tun/tap file descriptor with `f = os.open("/dev/net/tun", 'r+w')` it says you should choose only one option which are `create` `append` `read` `write`. But i need to be able to read and write from/into it. so i had to add `buffering=0`, Now it works with read and write . But the speed of reading and writing of the tun is slow. I think it is related to buffering that i set it to 0

 
I want to know that is the speed of reading and writing related to buffering?

What i have to do to be able to have the tun opened with read and write ability without setting buffering to 0?

Comment: Opening with `write` or `append` means you can also read. Buffering is not required.

Comment: From https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files: "`r+` opens the file for both reading and writing". Did you try that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r

Comment: i tried both `r+` and `w` for reading and writing but not worked

Comment: when i use `r+` or `w+` says `io.UnsupportedOperation: File or stream is not seekable.`

Comment: i think what you guys saying is about files not tun/tap